# Getting error during Ionic, Its not working when try to start new app (ionic version 4.8.0)

Tags: angular, ionic4

Trying a lot about below

`ionic start helloWorld blank`

Getting error with above after start with ionic

```
(node:53519) ExperimentalWarning: The http2 module is an experimental API.
⠹ Downloading and extracting blank starter (100.00%) 
events.js:193
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

ZlibError: zlib: Cannot read property 'length' of null
    at Unzip.Zlib.(anonymous function) (/Users/ahmadkhan/.nvm/versions/node/v9.0.0/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/minizlib/index.js:126:21)
    at Unzip.write (/Users/XXXX/.nvm/versions/node/v9.0.0/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/minizlib/index.js:247:21)
    at Unzip.flush (/Users/XXXX/.nvm/versions/node/v9.0.0/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/minizlib/index.js:206:10)
    at Unzip.end (/Users/XXXX/.nvm/versions/node/v9.0.0/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/minizlib/index.js:213:10)
    at Unpack.end (/Users/XXXX/.nvm/versions/node/v9.0.0/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/tar/lib/parse.js:416:21)
    at IncomingMessage.onend (_stream_readable.js:598:10)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:322:30)
    at emitNone (events.js:120:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:218:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1054:12)
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it with some research, issue was Node version (9.0.0) with latest ionic (4.8.0) I believe, 
after upgrading my Node (v10.15.0) its started working fine. 
Thanks